# Flutter scrolling Row

Tags: flutter, scroll

i have a Row inside a listview that it does not scroll with the rest of listview content i wanted to be scrollable, by the wat the cards inside the listView scrolls fine but not the row, i tried to put it inside a Stack , but still same problem

here is my code

```
    return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar()
  body: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.Prochaines_route);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Color(0xFFe0f2f1),
              ),
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  "Prochianes",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF30a6ca),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.EnCours_route);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Text("En cours"),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.Termines_route);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Text("Terminés"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.black),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.yellow),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.green),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.brown),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
    ],
  ),
);
```

i have a Row inside a listview that it does not scroll with the rest of listview content i wanted to be scrollable, by the wat the cards inside the listView scrolls fine but not the row, i tried to put it inside a Stack , but still same problem

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you want it to scrol horizontally?

Comment: nope vertically

Comment: I copy and pasted your code but instead of `Card(...)` I put a `Container(height: 10000, width: 300, color: Colors.red,),` and it worked fine

Comment: I mean the row scrolled vertically and exited from up of screen

Comment: i tried as u said but still i had the same problem whenever i scroll the row stays fixed on top gonna edit my post with the exactly code please check again.

Comment: I checked with your new code and its scrolling with cards!

Comment: the only change I made was commenting `Navigator.pushNamed` lines which aren't related

Comment: I copied your new code and Row widget is scrolling correctly!!
The only thing that is not scrolling is the app bar

Comment: still suffering the same issue , i even test it on another emulator, whenever i scroll the row dissapears

Comment: oh god what i was aking on the beginning i mean i wanted to be fixed and always visible

Comment: Isn't this what you want? to make the row disappear on scroll as it is inside the scroll widget!!!?

Comment: Hahaha! just put list view inside a column and put the row inside the column not inside the list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.Prochaines_route);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Color(0xFFe0f2f1),
              ),
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  "Prochianes",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF30a6ca),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.EnCours_route);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Text("En cours"),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // Navigator.pushNamed(context, route.Termines_route);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Text("Terminés"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.black),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.yellow),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.green),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.brown),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
        ],
),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the widget row to a ListView and do the following:

```
Widget myWidget() {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 100, // Important to set a high
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // Set the scroll direction
      shrinkWrap: true, // Set the shrinkWrap to true
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        // You can add as many as you want ... 
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```